# update height in real time jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a parent div #lobipanel-multiple and two child divs with class lobipanel-parent-sortable. im setting lobipanel-parent-sortable div's height with that of parent div which is #lobipanel-multiple using setHeight. when page loads it sets the height of lobipanel-parent-sortable div to that of parent div i.e 617px. but inside lobipanel-parent-sortable div there are collapsible panels. so when i collapse those panels the height of  lobipanel-parent-sortable doesnt update..it remains fixed at 617px due to which there is white space and also the vertical scrollbar is still present. ideally the height of lobipanel-parent-sortable div should update but its not happening.
Thanks in advance.

HTML Code---------------------------------

```
<div id="lobipanel-multiple">
<div class="col-md-6  lobipanel-parent-sortable">
<div class="panel">
Some content
</div>
<div class="panel">
Some content
</div>
<div>
<div class="col-md-6  lobipanel-parent-sortable">
<div class="panel">
Some content
</div>
<div class="panel">
Some content
</div>
<div>
</div>
```

Jquery Code--------------------------------------------------------

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setHeight() {
    ptheight = $( '#lobipanel-multiple' ).height();
    $('.lobipanel-parent-sortable').css('height', ptheight);
  };
  setHeight();
});
```

Comment: on collapse set height to auto $('.lobipanel-parent-sortable').css('height', 'auto');

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `height:auto` and that'll do the job

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setHeight() {
    $('.lobipanel-parent-sortable').css('height', 'auto');
  };
  setHeight();
});
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qaxwn5kh/)